# Textinput breaks view layout in React Native. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, textinput

Textinput breaks view layout. first ss all views normaly work but I click texinput breaks example in second ss we see textinput under the logo. How to fix it ?

```js
<TextInput
  value={values.username}
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder='Adınızı Giriniz..'
  onChangeText={handleChange('username')}
/>
```

[image: first screen shot]

[image: second screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you can use

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={-200}>
<ScrollView>
YOUR UI HERE
</ScrollView>
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Play with keyboardVerticalOffset so you can get the desired behavior. As this value differs in android and iOS so consider Platform.OS === 'ios'